# How can I open a file from Finder in Flutter App

Tags: swift, flutter, macos, dart

I am trying to open a file from the Finder app with my Flutter app. However, the method that is expected to be called when opening a file is never being invoked.

---

I've created a custom file extension for my flutter app and already registered it in the `Info.plist` for MacOS. Files of the custom type are already being recognized by the operating system and are displayed with the correct icon. Double clicking one of them opens or focuses my Flutter app.

I have read online that the correct way to listen to opened files on MacOS is to override the `application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])`method of `FlutterAppDelegate` in `AppDelegate.swift`. So far my code looks like this:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  ...  
  override func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL]) {
    ApplicationService.shared?.methodChannel.invokeMethod("print", arguments: "Hello World!")
  }
  ...
}
```

But as it seems, the method is never being called. It can't be methodChannel, as it successfully sends a print, when initialized.

I even tried removing all pub libraries from my project in order to see if any of them have an impact on the problem. Is it still possible that there is a Flutter plugin that is consuming the "OpenUrl" Event?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: "I am trying to open a file from the Finder app with my Flutter app."  What does that mean?  Are you trying to invoke your own application when the user double-clicks on a file of a certain type?  Or are you just selecting and opening a file with `NSOpenPanel`?

Comment: I was trying to invoke my own application when a user uses the Finder to double-clicks on a file of my custom file type. I finally found the problem though. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; Remove `NSDocumentClass` key from `Info.plst` under `CFBundleDocumentTypes`**

I finally found the solution!
Apparently, the `NSDocumentClass` of the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` was the culprit.
It was set to `NSDocument`. I think swift was trying to parse it as an object of that type. Removing the key from my `Info.plst` made the event finally go through and enabled me to listen to it in the `application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])` method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to detect the method call with something simple, e.g. with an Alert:

```swift
override func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL]) {
  showMessage("Hello", "world")
}

func showMessage(question: String, text: String) {
  let alert = NSAlert()
  alert.messageText = question
  alert.informativeText = text
  alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
  alert.alertStyle = .warning
  alert.runModal()
}
```

2. Make sure that your path/filename don't contain any special characters (like `mía música`), again, start with some simple file in your home directory

Comment: I've implemented the code and made sure that my path doesn't contain any special characters. Unfortunately, there is no alert being shown when I open the test file...

Comment: Thanks again for the hint with the alert!! It helped tons while searching for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])` might not work due to:

1. Incorrect file association: Check "CFBundleTypeRole" and "LSUIElement" in `Info.plist`.
2. URL encoding: Decode the `urls` using `URLDecoder`.
3. Method channel error: Verify method name and arguments on both sides.

Debug with logging and inspect values to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)
"CFBundleTypeRole" is set to "Editor" and the key "LSUIElement" is not set. I will do some research about that key. 
The method channel seems to work fine and the URLDecoder will come in handy, as soon as I actually get the urls. Right now the callback doesn't fire,  so I can't access the urls at all...